# Не воспроизводятся анимации Animator в Unity 2d и не выдаёт ошибок

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, unity3d

Недавно начал изучать Unity и столкнулся на мой взгляд с нерешаемой проблемой.

Заключается она в том, что при просмотре самой анимации через ctr+6 она работает как надо, но когда я запускаю прогу и проверяю эти анимации, то они не работают. Объясните почему?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class UI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject ListBar;
    private Animator anim;
    public bool lever = true; 

    private void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        
    }
    public void Hide_Show_ListBar()
    {
        if (lever == true)
        {
            anim.SetBool("IsPushOff", false);
            anim.SetBool("IsPushOn", true);
            lever = !lever;
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool ("IsPushOn", false);
            anim.SetBool("IsPushOff", true);
            lever = !lever;
        }
        
    }
}
```

В этом коде я задал объект anim к которому присваиваю компонент Animator, а далее в коде я задаю переменным, выполняющих функцию проверки нажатия на кнопу, некие значения. Кнопка по задумке и должна активировать анимации, путем изменения этих переменных.

вот как выглядит связка анимаций в Аниматоре:

[image: Связка анимаций в Animator]

Так выглядит переход от PanelOff к PanelSwipeUp:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А так от PanelOn к PanelSwipeDown:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Оставшиеся переходы происходят без условия, т.е. после окончания предыдущей анимации.

Так же могу приложить небольшой видео фрагмент работоспособности моей тестовой проги: [Тут](https://youtu.be/ZdA1U2-y6Jg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не указан объект, на на котором висит аниматор.

Сделайте переменную Animator anim публичной:

```
public Animator anim;
```

После чего в инспекторе перенесите объект в переменную anim

Comment: А разве этой строчкой кода я не получаю объект Animator без моего вмешательства:
'
private void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
'

Comment: нет, в данном контексте, она нечего не делает. Если моё решение вам помогло, то пометьте его, как решение

Comment: @Mr.AntinDer Чел, спасибо огромное! реально, предложенный тобою вариант и оказался решением)